# Strange error plotting more than 30 series of a DF

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, pycharm

I have 2 Data Frames of series of numbers with the following shape: [637 rows x 50 columns]
I'm trying to plot each series separately using this code:

```
for i in range(1, 51):
    series[i].plot(figsize=(10, 6), linewidth=1, alpha=0.5)
    ema_df[i].plot(figsize=(10, 6), linewidth=1, alpha=0.5)
```

And I also have another 2 DFs with the shape: [637 rows x 12 columns] after those which I'm also trying to plot with a similar code:

```
for i in range(1, 13):
    series[i].plot(figsize=(10, 6), linewidth=1, alpha=0.5)
    ema_df[i].plot(figsize=(10, 6), linewidth=1, alpha=0.5)
```

I'm using Pycharm with Github Copilot plugin.

The strange error which I didn't find any mention to it on the net is that the first loop only plots 30 graphics despite I changed the size of the plots from 16x9 to 10x6, and after plotting them it starts to return:

```
Error: failed to send plot to http://127.0.0.1:63342
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_display/datalore/display/display_.py", line 86, in _send_display_message
    urllib_request.urlopen(url, buffer)

urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

and the second loop of 12 series DF returns the same error.

If I split the first loop in 2: One from 1 to 31, and the other from 31 to the end, the first one print the graphics without any problem, but the second one returns the same error, and either the 12 series loop.

Finally I commented the first loop for plotting the 50 graphics, and the loop for the 12 graphics worked without any problem.

I know there are many questions answered about the `HTTP Error 429`, but all of them are web requests related, and I'm just trying to plot graphics with any web involved in the process.
That's why I named the error as "strange" (at least for me).

I don't know why an `HTTP Error 429` is involved, and how to fix it to get all the graphics.

I thought it could be a memory issue involved, so I increased the memory available in Pycharm Settings, because I have 32 Gb Of RAM to work with, but the problem persist.

Finally I decided to ask for your help.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the "so long" description of my problem.

Comment: It appears to be an issue with PyCharm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-62181/SciView-urllib.error.HTTPError-HTTP-Error-429-Too-Many-Requests-when-28-plots-are-generated